# Segfault when going back to Object Mode, on unrelated data

Tags: python, edit-mode, memory-management, object-mode

I am writing an Addon.  I have a list of Vectors:

```
centers = [p.center for p in obj.data.polygons]
```

In a later section of code, I do the following to a different object:

```
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.select_all(action='DESELECT')
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='OBJECT')
```

After this return to Object Mode, the earlier list of centers no longer points to anything, and any reference to it causes a segfault.

This is not the only mode change in the code, but the segfault happens only at this one location.
The segfault remains even if I operate on centers_copy = centers.copy().
The segfault goes away if I inelegantly cast the Vectors to lists and back:

```
centers_list = [list(elt) for elt in centers]
centers = [Vector(elt) for elt in centers_list]
```

What, precisely, is causing this segfault?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Use a copy**

```
centers = [p.center.copy() for p in obj.data.polygons]
```

Similarly for `obj.location`

```
>>> C.object.location
Vector((3.3187315464019775, 1.0073195695877075, 7.229274749755859))

>>> v = C.object.location
>>> vc = C.object.location.copy()
>>> C.object.location = (0, 0, 0)
>>> v
Vector((0.0, 0.0, 0.0))

>>> vc
Vector((3.3187315464019775, 1.0073195695877075, 7.229274749755859))
```

`v` is a reference to the object location. It is bound to the object. Removing the object and trying to reference `v` again will lead to a seg fault.

Use `v = C.object.location.copy()` for an unbound "snapshot" copy.  (casting to list and back was doing this too)

Note `centers.copy()` was still a copy of a list whose items were references to a polygon and hence the mesh.

As pointed out by @MartinZ you can also set the select values in object mode. The `foreach_set(prop, values)` method is faster than iterating and setting, eg for polygons

```
>>> me = C.object.data
>>> me.polygons.foreach_set("select", [False] * len(me.polygons))
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks batFINGER.  I will start a new habit of using copies of all locations.

Comment: That's really cool. I actually timed it on a high poly object and apparently that is a lot faster, more than 20 times faster to my surprise in my test at least.

Answer (score 1):

That's weird. It crashes Blender when I try to recheck `centers` valuues in the console after edit mode switch. Must be some bug in the Blenders Python API. You could deselect everything without switching to edit mode. This seems to work:

```
import bpy

d = bpy.context.object.data

centers = [p.center for p in d.polygons]

for x in [v for v in d.vertices] + [p for p in d.polygons] + [e for e in d.edges]:
    x.select = False

print(centers)
```